# Facebook App subdomain

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm using the Facebook Javascript SDK to do authentication on a website.  My app's "Site URL" is example.com, but I need it to work on www.example.com as well.  Any ideas how I can make it work with this alternate URL, or subdomains in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant have it work on both. If you really need it to then you have to edit your code to redirect to whatever page is set up in the application settings.

To redirect you can try something like this in the 'head' of your html page:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var url = window.location;

    if(url.indexOf('www') != -1 )
    {
      window.location = "example.com";
    }
</script>
```